# Excel Expense Report Challenge- Deduct an expense from account according to dropdown name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a report that contains 2 dropdown accounts (wallet 1 + wallet 2) and I need to create a formula in E5 & E6 that deducts the price per product from the relevant account according to the dropdown list.

If for example Wallet 1 spends 0,50 for sugar, deduct 0.50 it from the 2000 amount and show the sum in E5.

I don't know if it would be something like

`=IF(A9="Wallet 1", C5-E9)` but for the whole A Column and E column accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUMIF` function to add up all the prices that have a given value (e.g. "Wallet 1") in column A, then subtract that value from the initial amount in column C. Enter this formula in cell E5:

```
=$C5-SUMIF($A$9:$A$12,$B5,$E$9:$E$12)
```

Then copy that formula to cell E6. The `SUMIF` function is calculating the sum of all values in E9:E12 that have the same value in A9:A12 as is in B5.